Double Jump Issu
this month we have a project and our project is to create a game and we already does the jump with the event get.keypressed but we don't know and we can't find the solution to implement a double jump
our game is for two player so we put the movement on keyboard keys
here is our code
key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if key[pygame.K_w] and not self.jumped:
    self.vel_y = -15
    self.jumped = True
if not key[pygame.K_w]:
    self.jumped = False

for one player
here is our gravity
self.vel_y += 1

if self.vel_y > 10:
    self.vel_y = 10

dy += self.vel_y

and here is our parameters
self.image_right = pygame.image.load('images/perso/joueur1/mouvement/persodroite.png').convert_alpha()
self.image_left = pygame.image.load('images/perso/joueur1/mouvement/persogauche.png').convert_alpha()
self.image_still = pygame.image.load('images/perso/joueur1/mouvement/perso1.png').convert_alpha()
self.image = self.image_still
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
self.rect.x = x
self.rect.y = y
self.vel_y = 0
self.jumped = False

we had try to put a parameters to count the number of jump
